# How can i change the character set of mysql database with php without changing the correct ones?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, iconv, iso-8859-1

I'm currently using a MySQL database, and the previous guy that maintained the database has changed the character set from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. Now there is a problem that every ä turns into Ã¤. Now I've wrote code to change all of the records in the entire database. But apparently there are some words that are correctly written.
So for example you have a word like `PÃ¶ytÃ¤krono` and a word like `Sisäänkirjautuminen`.
If I use `iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', PÃ¶ytÃ¤krono)` it will give `Pöytäkrono`,
but when I use `iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', Sisäänkirjautuminen)` it will give `S`.
Because the database is quite big I want to do it automatically, but I don't want that the words that are correctly spelled/written to be changed only the ones that are wrong.

Comment: MySQL is only one of the actors. See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: So you have *some* data in your database which has a screwed up encoding and you have *some* data which is correct? Or does [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) help?

Answer (score 0):

You can change database storage encoding just like that and it will work in that the database *stores* strings in UTF-8. This doesn't buy you anything by itself.

But things that also need to change:

- Text editor encoding needs to be set to UTF-8. PHP strings directly in source code have the encoding your text editor has been set to.
- The database<->php *transport* encoding, which probably doesn't even exist in your code because it defaults to ISO-8859-1. For UTF-8 you need to explicitly call `mysql_set_charset("utf8")` before making queries.
- The website encoding declaration, also defaults to ISO-8859-1. You need to explicitly call `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8")` or configure for example apache to do it automatically.

Comment: but UTF-8 has the problem that it can't store or display ä or ö, I've solved it with a regex : $regex = "(([äöÄÖa-zA-Z0-9]*+\s*)+)"; this takes care of the values that are displayed correctly but still makes it possible to change the wrong values.